Can you export a slackbot you created so someone else can use the same permissions and setup?
I am creating a slackbot for the first time, and it is going to run locally on my own workspace. Is there a way to export a slackbot with all it's permissions and setup so you can share it with another workspace? I'm wanting to have a colleague set it up on their computer, so they can play around and add different permissions to their own version of this slackbot. Can it only be distributed via link in the manage distribution tab?

Yes, slack.manifest.yml file can be used for this. You declare there all the settings, commands, scopes etc. and it can be imported to your new environment.
refference: Slack Docs

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
